# Setting a swf file to only work from a specific domain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an as3 swf, and I want to make sure it can only be loaded from a specific domain. So for example if the my file is f.swf and my specific allowed domain is www.google.com, you would only be able to load the f.swf from www.google.com, and not from any other domain. How can this be achieved?

Comment: check the loaderinfo instance of your swf, it has everything you need to check where it is currently loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I think it's not very helpful. The crossdomain.xml file is for clients consuming the swf, not the swf itself (I want to have code inside the swf file that would whitelist only a specific domain).